# Compare two dates with one in MomentJS

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

Good morning, I tried to google how to do this a couple of times, checked the docs and etc, but got no luck so far.
Basically what I'm trying to do is: I have three dates, one representing today date and two representing the dates when a certain TV show will air, as shown in the code below:

```
    function handleAccordionExpanded(title: string, startTime: string, endTime: string) {
    const today = moment();

    let startTimeFormatted = moment(today.toISOString().slice(0,10) + ' ' + startTime).tz('America/Sao_Paulo');
    let endTimeFormatted = moment(today.toISOString().slice(0,10) + ' ' + endTime).tz('America/Sao_Paulo');

    if (startTimeFormatted.unix() >= today.unix() && endTimeFormatted.unix() <= today.unix()) {
        console.log(startTimeFormatted);
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Both the startTime and the endTime are not in my current timezone, so I need to convert then to -03:00

This piece of code is very important to create the startTimeFormatted:

```
moment(today.toISOString().slice(0,10) + ' ' + startTime).tz('America/Sao_Paulo');
```

Because I need to know the current year, month and day in order to create today's date, the startTime will always give me the representation in hh:mm (09:15, 12:15, 15:55, 22:15, etc).

What I'm actually trying to do is to compare hours and minutes, not the full date, but got no luck with that as well.

I was trying with the Date object from JS before trying my luck with MomentJS.

Any tips will be welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it with the following comparison:

```
     if ( today.isBetween(startTimeFormatted, endTimeFormatted) ) {
        return true;
    }
```